# A macro that reads variables until the variable is in a given interval in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a macro that reads variables until the the variable (in my case type int variable) is in the interval [min,max]. I created a macro that checks if the variable is in an interval but i can't use it properly in the other macro, i stuck in an infinite loop. Here's my code, can you help me, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CHECK(x, n, m) ((x) > (n) && (x) < (m) ? 1 : 0)
#define READ(TEXT, P, VAR, min, max)                                           \
  do {                                                                         \
    printf(TEXT ": ");                                                         \
    scanf("%" #P, &VAR);                                                       \
  } while (x = (CHECK((VAR), (min), (max))) == 0)
int main(void) {
  int x, min1, max1;
  printf("min=");
  scanf("%d", &min1);
  printf("max=");
  scanf("%d", &max1);
  READ("x=", g, x, min1, max1);
  // int i=CHECK(x,min1,max1);
  // printf("%d\n",i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while( x=(CHECK...` remove `x=`. It is not part of the macro and will literally expand.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Just applied clang format on it nothing else...hmm. Edit: Rolledback.

Comment: The formatting was consistent with the source, the \ on the first macro doesn't make sens

Comment: Yea..I mean I may be dumb sometimes, but clang-format shouldn't alter the code meaning.

Comment: `scanf("%"` won;t work. You need to add a type character: `scanf("%d"`

Answer (score 0):

The `CHECK` macro looks fine. I think the `READ` macro should be:

```
#define READ(TEXT, P, VAR, min, max)                                           \
  do {                                                                         \
    printf(TEXT ": ");                                                         \
  } while (scanf("%" P, &VAR)!=1 || CHECK((VAR), (min), (max))) == 0)
```

The changes are:

- `scanf` return value is checked
- the assignment of `x=(CHECK...` is removed because `x` is not a macro parameter and any assignment was done by `scanf`.

Your variable `g` in main is not defined. I think the call should be:

```
READ("x=", "d", x, min1, max1);
```

now the strings `"%"` and `"d"` are appended by the compiler to form `"%d"`

In these cases it can be handy to have the compiler (pre-processor) generate the pre-processor result and check that if the macro expanded as you wanted.

Comment: Don't you want `scanf(...)==1 && CHECK(...) == 0`? As it is [with `||`], if anything is read sucessfully, the check will never be performed and shouldn't the check [failure] stop the loop?